# Compass file to import not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, compass-sass

I'm currently undergoing the process of upgrading our Rails 3.0.* app to 3.2.13

In the past, we have used Compass (via the compass-rails) gem extensively. Our stylesheets are located in public/sass and use compass in the following way:

```
@import "compass/reset/utilities";
```

Upon upgrading, I am now moving my stylesheets into the app/assets/stylesheets directory

One of the files @imports compass/reset/utilities but I am receiving the following error when it attempts to compile:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset/utilities. Load path: blahblahblah (in blahblahblah/app/assets/stylesheets/common/reset.css.scss)"
```

I also have a compass.rb config file that sets the sass_dir to public/sass but I'm not sure how to adjust this to point to the correct new directory.

I have a gist available at https://gist.github.com/naderhen/b0908c55739c78cb45bd with the reset.scss and compass.rb file

In my gemfile, I have the following

```
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

    gem "compass-rails"
    gem "compass-960-plugin"
    gem "compass_twitter_bootstrap"
end
```

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated. I've tried a number of the solutions here on SO but none have worked for this particular issue.

Thanks!

Comment: i answered a similar question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108679/sasssyntaxerror-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-compass-in-production/23122076#23122076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your Gemfile and remove , '~> 3.2.3' from the gem 'sass-rails' line.  Run 'bundle update sass-rails'.  This will update sass-rails to version 3.2.6 (current as of 5/31/2013), which seems to know where to find the compass files.