# Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am suddenly getting this error in development and in production on deployment.

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

error (in production)

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
Load paths:
/srv/www/myapp/releases/20141001060418/app/assets/images
/srv/www/myapp/releases/20141001060418/app/assets/javascripts
/srv/www/myapp/releases/20141001060418/app/assets/stylesheets
/srv/www/myapp/releases/20141001060418/vendor/assets/javascripts
/srv/www/myapp/releases/20141001060418/vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

Comment: Well if i was you i would check on that bootstrap-sprockets.css.scss file and make sure it's there and ready to roll for Sass to precompile ;-)

Comment: Possible Duplicate Question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108679/sasssyntaxerror-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-compass-in-production

Comment: Dont forget to restart your server

Answer (score 94):

After making changes to Gemfile, do not forget to restart the server with `rails s`

Restarting the rails server worked like a charm! :D

Comment: This fixed it for me. Bootstrap gems require server restart to work.

Comment: I restarted the server as well but I am wondering why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 28):

I solved this issue by upgrading bootstrap-sass

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'
```

Comment: I need a similar change, but I recommend you use the syntax `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'` as it will give you minor version updates rather than locking you into a specific release.

Answer (score 13):

Please restart you rails server after every changes in Gemfile

```
rails server
```

Answer (score 9):

**For the Sass version of Bootstrap 5** in versions of rails *before* 6
use

```
gem `bootstrap`
```

**For Sass versions of Bootstrap 3 and 2** Make sure you don't have

```
gem 'bootstrap'  # Remove this line
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

It should just be

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, but in my case I had both 'bootstrap-sass' and 'sass-rails' in my Gemfile. Removing 'sass-rails' and leaving just 'bootstrap-sass' like you suggested here worked in that case, too.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it in following steps:

1. List item
2. copying the "bootstrap.css" in my "app/assets/stylesheets/ (it was missing)
3. gem install autoprefixer-rails (also modify Gemfile)
4. gem install sprockets (also modify Gemfile)
5. bundle install
6. RESTART server (not just refreshing page)

Comment: One plus for `restart server` step.

Comment: Restarting the server.. Oh my!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved the issue.

Go to [Bootstrap for Sass Github page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) and follow the instructions:

1. Add the following to the Gemfile

   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
   gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
2. Run the command
   `bundle install`
3. Start/restart the server

   rails s

Also, make sure the file has .scss extension (or .sass for Sass syntax). If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead. If this file exists, it will be served instead of Sass, so rename it.
Then, remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements from the sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.

Comment: Thanks for the "restart the server" line, I was stuck 4 hours on it.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed the same behaviour. In my case i have removed the version of the gem 'bootstap-sass' and it worked. There might be compatibility issue with the gem version which was causing the problem.

Gem file

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

After making changes in the gem file perform following commands:

```
bundle install
```

If the server is already running then stop it by "**CTRL+C**" and start the server again

```
rails s
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Gemfile you need to add the bootstrap-sass gem, and ensure that the sass-rails gem is present - it is added to new Rails applications by default.

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'
gem 'rails', '5.0.0'
```

bundle install and restart your server to make the files available through the pipeline.
Import Bootstrap styles in **app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:**

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

bootstrap-sprockets must be imported before bootstrap for the icon fonts to work.
Make sure the file has .scss extension (or .sass for Sass syntax). If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead. If this file exists, it will be served instead of Sass, so rename it:

> $ mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css **TO:**
>   app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

Then, remove all the `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree .` statements from the sass file. Instead, use `@import` to import Sass files.
**e.g**

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

**To:**

```
@import require_tree .
@import require_self
```

Do not use `*= require` in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins or variables.
Bootstrap JavaScript depends on jQuery. If you're using `Rails 5.1+`, add the jquery-rails gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'

$ bundle install
```

Require Bootstrap Javascripts in

> app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

`bootstrap-sprockets` and `bootstrap` should not both be included in

> application.js

.
`bootstrap-sprockets` provides individual Bootstrap Javascript files (alert.js or dropdown.js, for example), while `bootstrap` provides a concatenated file containing all Bootstrap Javascripts.

**This will fix the error**

```
Copied @github
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but you've pretty much copy pasted the gems readme.

Answer (score 1):

This error mostly comes in rails 3.2.x versions.
If you are using rails version 3.2 you have to specify a special version in your gem file like below:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'
```

It will resolve the problem for `rails -v '3.2.0'`

Answer (score 1):

put this in gem file

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

then run `$ bundle install`

Restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this message when running integration tests, make sure that your asset gems are included in the test group.

For example, change:

`group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
end`

To:

`group :assets, :test do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
end`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

```
sass::syntaxerror: file to import not found or unreadable: config/variables.
```

, I opened a new css file (I called it custom.css) then copied all the css to the file. On application.css I removed the

> @import "config/variables" plus all the other @imports

This worked for me, I hope it does work for you too!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you run the following commands after adding this gem to your Gemfile
put this inside your Gemfile

```
    gem "bootstrap-sprockets", "~>3.3"
    gem "bootstrap"
```

now stop your server and run the following:

```
    bundle install
    rails server
```

to restart your server. Refresh your browser and you should see changes reflect immediately. 
In production you may have to run this command to precompile your assets:

```
    bundle exec bin/rake assets:precompile
```

It worked for me. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I get `Could not find gem 'bootstrap-sprockets' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.` when I try that.

Comment: you should have the gem in your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar error in development environment:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNnjG.png)

I solved this problem by-

1. In my gemfile, I added them -

   **gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.2.1'**

   **gem 'jquery-rails'**
2. In application.js file,add these  -

   **//= require jquery3**

   **//= require popper**

   **//= require bootstrap-sprockets**
3. In the file with **.scss** extension, simply add -

   **@import "bootstrap";**

   After that, just run **bundle install**

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that kind of issue.
If you can see lower version of bootstrap-sass than 3.4.1 in "Gemfile.lock",
please upgrade bootstrap-sass gem version.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the (.css) to (.scss). Then in there I just have this..

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
@import "bootstrap";
```

I also have @import "boostrap" in the application.js file. This is just how it worked for me - not a 100% proper fix - it works though.

Answer (score -1):

I solved My Issue By Removing

```
gem 'bootstrap'
```