# Can't run bootsrap : couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Having some problems installing bootstrap onto my rails project.

howing /Users/muhname/Photogur/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:

couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type 'application/javascript'

my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

my css:

```
/  *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
/  *= require_tree .
/  *= require_self
/ /*

@import "bootstrap"
```

gem: 'bootstrap-sass', '3.0.2.1'

Anybody who might know what the issue is? thanks!

Comment: How did you included `bootstrap-sass', '3.0.2.1'` in the Gemfile? I guess, if this was included in `group :assets`, please move out from this and it should work. This is because, I think you are using Rails4 and it drops support for assets group in gemfile. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16406204/5076451)

Comment: Will you please post the code block around the error you mentioned? Users/muhname/Photogur/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb: line #10

Comment: This would be the correct solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28322353/5645769

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try removing bootstrap-sprockets from your application.js. It doesn't need to be there, and it's creating the error.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

> couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type
>   'application/javascript'

The only solution was to comment off:

```
# gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

And add instead:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

In the `Gemfile`, I hope this helps other members.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error:

> couldn't find file 'bootstrap-material-design.js' with type
>   'application/javascript'

and I can fix removing this line in application.js

```
//=require bootstrap-material-design.js
```

Try it!