# Why doesn't bootstrap-sass work with Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I've added bootstrap-sass to my gemfile. I've followed the instructions here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.  Modifications have been made to the javascript/application.js.scss and stylesheet/application.css.scss files per the above link.

When I try to view a new controller, I get this:

> Sass::SyntaxError in Test#index Showing
>   /Users/myuser/Rails/myproject/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
>   where line #5 raised:
>
> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
>
> */ @import "bootstrap-sprockets"; @import "bootstrap";

I haven't added any bootstrap code to the Rails app yet.  It's a new Rails app with only the above modifications and one new controller.

I did run bundle install but it seemed to not install anything.  The output was this:

> Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 56 gems now installed. Use
>   `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

along with a bunch of `Using`s.  I did see these entries:

```
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.5.1
Using bootstrap-sass 0.0.2
```

Any idea why I'm getting the above error?

Comment: `javascript/application.js.scss` is not a CSS file, it's javascript. You only change your CSS file extension to use SCSS.

Comment: You may restart your server like this suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135126/sasssyntaxerror-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-bootstrap-sprockets

Comment: Do you have the  gem 'sass-rails' in your gemfile?

Comment: I've renamed the files.  Restarted the server.  Yes - sass-rails is in the gem file.  Still no change.

Answer (score 1):

you got your files a bit wrong.

make sure you have 'app/assets/javascripts/application.js with the following content

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

and 'app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss' with following

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

pay attention to file names and extensions

Comment: I have the same extensions now.  I moved "require bootstrap-sprockets" above "require_tree ." but still no change.  I get the same error.

Comment: since its a new app, I assume shouldn't have any other files. 
make sure you have two of the files exactly as above and then don't forget to restart the server

Comment: I have a few more requires in my files than you.  There is one project this is working. It's also a new project.  There is no difference with the files.  I do remember after running bundle install that bootstrap-sass displayed an ascii ghost and you could tell it installed.  With this other project, that didn't happen.  bootstrap-sass does show as installed in my local gems.

Comment: 1 `rails new foo`
2.  add   to gemfile `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'`
3. `bundle`
4. `mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`
5. remove  from application.scss
   `*= require_tree .
   *= require_self`

5. add to application.scss `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";`

6.  put right befor tree in application js 
`//= require bootstrap-sprockets`

may be you still have  '=* require ' in scss file

Comment: may be you still have  '=* require ' in scss file ? you shouldn't

Comment: I found the issue.  It was a misspelling on the bootstrap-sass gem in the gem file.  Although I had to delete the folder and start over before anything would work.  Had to even create the app with a completely new name.  Go ahead and start with the gazillion down votes.

Comment: it's unlikely to be a misspelling, would've been totally different error. and `bundle install` wouldn't succeed