# The error is saying it can't find bootstrap but i've installed it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrapping

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Books#index
Showing /Users/me/apps/rails/clones/book_review/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:
  /Users/me/apps/rails/clones/book_review/app/assets/config
  /Users/me/apps/rails/clones/book_review/app/assets/images
  /Users/me/apps/rails/clones/book_review/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/apps/rails/clones/book_review/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/apps/rails/clones/book_review/node_modules
Extracted source (around line #18):
16
17


 @import "bootstrap";

Rails.root: /Users/me/apps/rails/clones/book_review

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
```

Comment: Make sure to restart your rails server (ctrl+c).

If this doesnt fix the issue, please add the output of ``bundle list``

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987649/bootstrap-rails-not-working) can help

Answer (score 0):

What exactly have you installed? Providing your `bundle list` may help.

Things to try:

- Run `bundle install` if you haven't already
- Restarting your Rails server
- Requiring bootstrap in your `application.js`
- Running `rake assets:precompile`
- Add require `the-gem-name` to `config/application.rb` to explicitly require it
- Try a different version of the gem
- As a last resort, you can download the bootstrap files yourself and include them in your assets