# Receiving error when installing bootstrap-sass gem in my ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bootstrap-sass, cloud9

I've been learning Ruby on Rails for the last few days and i'm following tutorials from a book.
I'm working on an app which requires importing bootstrap however i'm having trouble installing it into my project.

I'm using Ruby version 2.3.1 and Rails version 5.1.1 and i'm using the [cloud9](http://c9.io/) coding environment

I create a new app with the following command:

```
rails new bootstrap_app
```

The next instruction is to "add the bootstrap gem to the gemfile" with the following command:

```
gem 'bootstrap‐sass' , '~> 3.3.6'
```

I do this and I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command bootstrap-sass,
```

I looked up this error and I found it on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135126/sasssyntaxerror-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-bootstrap-sprockets) however "restarting the server" didn't work in my case.

The next instruction in the tutorial, is the command

```
bundle install
```

I do this and it tells me a list of dependencies that are installed (bootstrap is not listed)

I tried the command `gem install bootstrap-sass` and it said it installed the gem successfully however when i try to import bootstrap in my CSS file as follows:

```
@import "bootstrap‐sprockets" ;
@import "bootstrap";
```

i get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap%E2%80%90sprockets"):
```

any ideas on how i can get this working? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you copy/paste `gem 'bootstrap‐sass' , '~> 3.3.6'` into your command line. But you need to open the `Gemfile` file and add the line there.

Comment: @Wukerplank That makes more sense thank you. I see the Gemfile now in the app folder. So I have added the line gem 'bootstrap‐sass' , '~> 3.3.6' to the Gemfile and I have run bundle install but i'm getting an error: "Could not find gem 'bootstrap‐sass (~> 3.3.6)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.".. but the source is listed at the top of the Gemfile as follows: source 'https://rubygems.org' ..any ideas?

Comment: Put both these in your `Gemfile`: `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'` then run `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks @CD-RUM but the sass-rails was already in my Gemfile. gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0' and i did run bundle install after. it successfully installed the bundle but i am getting the error "File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap‐sprockets."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CD-RUM stated, you will need to add both the `gem bootstrap-sass` & `gem sass-rails` in to your Gemfile.  I would also suggest adding `gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'` as well since the newer version of sprockets that comes with rails 5 has had some issues working well with Bootstrap. Then run `bundle install`.

You will also want to rename your `application.css` file to `application.scss`
and add the import files (`@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` & `@import "bootstrap"`) there . Now restart your server.

Read through the Ruby on Rails installation instructions here: [bootsrap-sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) & if you're still having issues consider changing the version of the bootstrap-sass gem to an earlier version (I use `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'`) since some people seem to experience version conflicts.

Comment: Thanks @BrandonElder but the sass-rails was already in my Gemfile. gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'. I have followed all the guidelines including renaming application.css file to application.scss and also taking out *= require_self and *= require_tree in application.scss file and using import. I also added //= require bootstrap‐sprockets to application.js however still no luck. The project works when I take out import "bootstrap‐sprockets" ; and just use import "bootstrap"; but its not really ideal to leave it out. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Hmm....  Do you have the sprockets gem in your Gemfile?  I would try adding `gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'`

Comment: Thanks. Ok ive just added what you said to the Gemfile and ran "bundle install" again. and then restarted my server but I still get an error saying "File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap‐sprockets." hmm

Comment: It might also help to not specify the version of `gem 'sass-rails'`.  Rails will find the newest version of sass-rails gem that works.

Comment: Hmm... yeah that's strange.  I can't think of anything else that might help at the moment.  Sounds like you've done everything that I normally do when adding bootstrap to a Rails project.

Comment: Could be some kind of compatibility issue with the gem versions.  Try changing to `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'`.  I'm pretty sure that the latest version has some bugs but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that but had no luck. I was wondering what version of ruby and also rails are you using?

Comment: Dang...I'm stumped.  I'm using Rails 5 and I believe Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually i've just tried creating a new project and have followed the steps again to add bootstrap including using the version you mentioned: 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1' and it is running fine on the server so far. Maybe it didn't work in the last project because I was trying to install it mid-way through having worked on the project. So fingers crossed it will keep running successfully in this project after i incorporate some bootstrap styling etc. I'll let you know. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Oh awesome!  Glad I could help Sarah.  Don't forget to accept my answer if it was helpful : )  I just added bootstrap to a new project last night and that is the process I used.  Also as a side note for your assets to work in production, you may have to change the line in `/config/environments/production.rb` from `config.assets.compile = false` to `config.assets.compile = true`.  Worth looking into at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145999/discussion-between-sarah-and-brandonelder).